# How do I assign a var from passed in function var?

Tags: javascript

```
function getTabContent(tabId){
    var c = tabbar._content.tabId.innerHTML;
    return c;
}
```

I want var c to evaluate to the passed in var. So if I call getTabContent('dash').
var c will be the value of tabbar._content.dash.innerHTML from the DOM. NOT the string tabbar._content.dash.innerHTML.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [square bracket syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators#Bracket_notation).

```
function getTabContent(tabId){
    return tabbar._content[tabId].innerHTML;
}
```

Comment: You could shorten the function to a single line by just returning the result directly.


`function getTabContent(tabId){  return tabbar._content[tabId].innerHTML;  }`